# Regex (.NET) - Unrecognized grouping construct

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm stumped on the following getting the following regex to work (VB.NET)

**Input:**

```
 +1.41 DS +0.93 DC x 3* @12.5 mm (4.00 Rx Calc)
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 +0.93
```

I've gotten as far as the following expression:

```
 DS[ \t]*[+\-][ \t]*\d{1,2}\.\d{2}
```

This returns a result of

```
DS +0.93
```

I need to return only +0.93 (without any leading whitespace), when i modify the Regex as:

```
(?DS[ \t]*)([+\-][ \t]*\d{1,2}\.\d{2})
```

I get the error unrecognized grouping construct, I don't understand why it's giving me this error. I think my non-matching group is incorrect, but i can't find why/where?

Comment: Have you checked my answer below? If you need any more clarifications, please let know.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a positive lookbehind here:

```
(?<=DS[ \t]*)[+-][\t ]*\d{1,2}\.\d{2}
 ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3DDS%5B%20%5Ct%5D*%29%5B%2B-%5D%5B%5Ct%20%5D*%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D&i=%20%2B1.41%20DS%20%2B0.93%20DC%20x%203*%20%4012.5%20mm%20%284.00%20Rx%20Calc%29)

To make sure you match the number and `DS` as whole words (with no letters, digits or `_` in front and at the back) use word boundaries:

```
(?<=\bDS[ \t]*)[+-][\t ]*\d{1,2}\.\d{2}\b
```

Or a negative lookahead `(?!\d)` after `\d{2}`:

```
(?<=\bDS[ \t]*)[+-][\t ]*\d{1,2}\.\d{2}(?!\d)
```

See [another regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5CbDS%5B%20%5Ct%5D*%29%5B%2B-%5D%5B%5Ct%20%5D*%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D%28%3F!%5Cd%29&i=%20%2B1.41%20DS%20%2B0.93%20DC%20x%203*%20%4012.5%20mm%20%284.00%20Rx%20Calc%29).

**Details**

- `(?<=\bDS[ \t]*)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location in string that is immediately preceded with `DS` as a whole word followed with 0+ spaces or tabs
- `[+-]` - a `+` or `-`
- `[\t ]*`  - 0+ spaces or tabs
- `\d{1,2}` -  1 or 2 digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\d{2}` - 2 digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately to the right of the current location.

[VB.NET demo](https://ideone.com/FPrq4v):

```
Dim my_rx As Regex = New Regex("(?<=\bDS[ \t]*)[+-][\t ]*\d{1,2}\.\d{2}(?!\d)")
Dim my_result As Match = my_rx.Match(" +1.41 DS +0.93 DC x 3* @12.5 mm (4.00 Rx Calc)")
If my_result.Success Then
    Console.WriteLine(my_result.Value) ' => +0.93
End If
```